# How to convert normal table to CkEditor Table

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

[image]
 above table is my table i want to convert this above table like below CkEditor table, is there any way,IS there any css property which can convert it to like below table

this Table is CkEditor table[image]

Comment: i think you can do it using two properties of css like border and box-shadow

Comment: i am new in css so your help will be appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can do some thing like [**This Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zucgmg2u/1/)

```
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
    border: 2px solid #eee; min-width:200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table you're using border-collapse:collapse, that's why it looks different. Use "separate" or don't set it at all.

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
table {
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```